# pegar texto selecionado pelo usuario

Tags: javascript, html

Galera eu tenho este código JavaScript abaixo com ele eu estou tentando pegar o texto selecionado pelo usuário dentro de um iframe, o iframe está com designMode="on" ou seja ele esta no modo editável, o problema e que não estou conseguido ao dar o 
alert(string_texto_selecionado);
 ele mim retorna apenas o alert sem nada.

alguém pode mim ajudar desde ja agradeço.

```
var tag_iframe=document.querySelector('.mine-editor-de-texto');

var conteudo_tag_iframe=tag_iframe.contentDocument || tag_iframe.contentWindow.document;

var texto_selecionado=window.getSelection(conteudo_tag_iframe.body);

var string_texto_selecionado=texto_selecionado.toString();

alert(string_texto_selecionado);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta direto:

`var string_texto_selecionado = document.querySelector('.mine-editor-de-texto').contentWindow.document.body.value;`

Comment: Obrigado Douglas Teles mais infelizmente não funcionou o resultado foi o mesmo ao dar alert(string_texto_selecionado); eli mim retornar um alert vazio.

Comment: Posta um exemplo do que você ta fazendo usando { }

Answer (score 0):

Galera eu consegui resolve meu problema e to postando a reposta, era só adicionar

frames['MINI_EDITOR_DE_TEXTO_D_NEVES']

assim consegue pegar o texto selecionado pelo usuário dentro do iframe, abaixo como meu código ficou, Agradeço pelo ajuda.

```
    var tag_iframe=document.querySelector('.mine-editor-de-texto');
    var conteudo_tag_iframe=tag_iframe.contentDocument || tag_iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var texto_selecionado=window.frames['MINI_EDITOR_DE_TEXTO_D_NEVES'].getSelection(conteudo_tag_iframe.body);
    var string_texto_selecionado=texto_selecionado.toString();
    alert(string_texto_selecionado);
```